# Create websocket server using nodejs that can be used to communicate with Android App

Tags: android, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I have created a websocket server from my localhost machine that can be used to communicate with an android app.

The server is written in Node.js and hosted on my machine

```
var HOST = "192.168.0.15";
var PORT = 6969;

var Sock = net.Socket();

net.createServer(function(sock) {

    Sock = sock;

    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server


        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data);

        sock.write(jsonStr);

        var buffer = "";

    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        Sock.emit("data", data);
    });
});
```

And my Android app uses Java Websocket with

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.0.15", 6969);
commsThread = new CommsThread(socket);
commsThread.start();
```

My Android device used to test my app and my server runs in the same network so they work fine.

However, when I deploy it in Heroku, it gives me an error.

NOTE: I have tried changing the HOST address and PORT address but to no avail.

I was told that Heroku doesn't support TCP socket server.

I am not sure if the example above is an TCP socket server.

If not, why are some of the alternatives I can use.

Cheers,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [socket.io-java-client](http://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) along with the socket.io module for Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable websockets in Heroku?

```
$ heroku labs:enable websockets
```